# Change a dialog's message while using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, message, progressdialog

I looked at a few other questions regarding a similar issue, and I figured out that I need to use the `onProgressUpdate` method to change the message of `ProgressDialog`.

For example, I have code like this that runs in the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackGround` (this is just a very small sample):

```
        byte[] data = getBytesFromFile(image);

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        pictures.dia.setProgress(30);
        pictures.dia.setMessage("Data beginning upload sequence...");

        URL connectURL = new URL(this.base_url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        pictures.dia.setProgress(40);
        pictures.dia.setMessage("Output Stream prepared...");
```

When I originally run thus, I get a Leaky Window error saying that I can't change `dia`'s message outside of `AsyncTask`.

So my question is, how do I use `onProgressUpdate` to set the message of `dia` when `dia`'s progress reaches a certain number? (i.e., when `dia`'s progress = 30, make it say "Data beginning upload sequence...")
`onProgressUpdate` must obviously always be checking `dia`'s progress (like a listener, I suppose)[if it doesn't already do this, how can I make it do this?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the `onProgressUpdate` method of `AsyncTask`. Create a new class that holds the progress percentage and the message only to be the `onProgressUpdate` method's only parameter.

In the onProgressUpdate, call `dia.setProgress` and `dia.setMessage`.

In your doInBackground method, call `publishProgress` with an instance of your new class that contains the new percentage and message. That will cause the `AsyncTask` to call `onProgressUpdate` on the main thread.

For example:

```
private static class TaskProgress {
    final int percentage;
    final String message;

    TaskProgress(int percentage, String message) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

In your AsyncTask (replace the ?s with the correct types for your implementation):

```
public ProgressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<?, TaskProgress, ?> {

    public void onProgressUpdate(TaskProgress progress) {
         pictures.dia.setProgress(progress.percentage);
         pictures.dia.setMessage(progress.message);
    }

    public ? doInBackground(?... params) {
        // ... your code       
        publishProgress(new TaskProgress(30, "A new update"));
        // ... your code 
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I see how this works.  I have one problem right now: I'm getting an error when I put `publishProgress(new TaskProgress(10, "Beginning sequence..."));` in some `runnable` code.  My runnable is called in the `doInBackground` method, but isn't physically in that method.  Also, the runnable later calls another method from another class, where I can't use `publishProgress`.  Any way around this?

Comment: Note: if I try `Task.publishProgress(new TaskProgress(10, "My message here..."));`, it says that publishProgress is not visible from the AsyncTask.  Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: You have to call publishProgress inside your doInBackground method.

Comment: Thats not the problem.  All my doInBackground method is is `uploader.run()`, where I run my Runnable code that is **outside** the `doInBackground` method.  Do you see the problem here?  `doInBackground` calls the runnable and nothing more, and I don't want to put the runnable inside `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that you should put the code for updating the views in `dia` in the `onProgressUpdate` method. To ensure that onProgressUpdate is called, though, you need to make calls to [`publishProgress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29).  Basically, you call publishProgress from your background thread and then the system, at some undefined time in the future, will invoke onProgressUpdate on the UI thread.

Comment: So instead of `pictures.dia.setProgress(some number)`, I should use `publishProgress(some number)`?  OK, from there though, how does `onProgressUpdate` display the right message I want?