# ProgressDialog setProgress and setMessage inside asyncTask don't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have asynktask that shows a progressDialog and update its value in doInBackground method. the methods code:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(cont);
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setTitle(cont.getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait));
    progress.setMessage(cont.getResources().getString(R.string.loadingImages));
    progress.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    progress.setProgress(2);
    //do some work on the database and network
    progress.setProgress(25);
    //Do some extra work
    for(int i = 0; i < itemImagesList.size(); i++){
        publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) itemImagesList.size()) * 100));
        //Do somework
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
    progress.setProgress(prog[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progress.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

The progressDialog value doesn't change at all! and if I tried to set the dialog message using:

```
progress.setMessage("At item "+i);
```

some exception occurs if I put it in the middle of the method, but in the first it works fine!

what's wrong?

Comment: You just need to remove progress.setProgress(2);, progress.setProgress(25); these from the doInBackground, and you can see your progress. because update progress already updating at UI

Comment: Have you tried this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970113/change-a-dialogs-message-while-using-asynctask?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your issue is related to `setIndeterminate(true);` You should set it to `false` if you want to have progress update (take a look at [Android setProgress doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int))), don't forget to also use `setMax()` to set progress max value to the desired one.

And as said Laurent you can change progress only on UI thread so you have to do it in `onProgressUpdate` and not in doInBackground

Answer (score 2):

You have to update progress value inside UI thread so in method onProgressUpdate of your AsyncTasK

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                    getActivity ().runOnUiThread (new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run () {

                          progress.setProgress(2);
                                       //do some work on the database and network
                          progress.setProgress(25);

                    }
                });
            //Do some extra work
            for(int i = 0; i < itemImagesList.size(); i++){
                publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) itemImagesList.size()) * 100));
                //Do somework
            }
        }
```